# How to insert multiple rows in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to insert multiple rows in database in  laravel when is insert it shows an error like this

```
Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `equipments` (`created_at`, `driver_id`, `price`, `product_id`) values (2019-04-11 12:48:43, 1, 12, 5), (2019-04-11 12:48:43, 1, 12, 5))
```

html form
http://prntscr.com/najtv9

dd response
http://prntscr.com/najst5

this is controller

```
    $product_id = $request->product_id;
    foreach($product_id as $k => $id)
            {
                $values[] = [
                    'driver_id' => $request->driver_id,
                    'product_id' => $request->product_id,
                    'price' => $request->price,
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now()
                ];

            }
DB::table('equipments')->insert($values);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: can you `dd($request->all())` and update your question with the output of it?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/najst5

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that error because,

```
$product_id = $request->product_id;
```

Above this is a string fetched from `$request` object. You can not loop a string.

**EDIT**

```
$product_id = $request->product_id;
foreach ($product_id as $k => $id) {
    $values[] = [
        'driver_id'  => $request->driver_id,
        'product_id' => $id,
        'price'      => $request->price[$k],
        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
    ];

}
```

This should work. Once replace your code with mine and check.

Comment: Trying to get property 'price' of non-object

Comment: @Shahid Now check, just little mistake, resolved and updated my answer.

Comment: @Shahid Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

you can use query builder insert function, this is how you can do it.

```
$rows = [
['2019-04-11 12:48:43', 1, 12, 5], 
['2019-04-11 12:48:43', 1, 12, 5]
];

DB::table('table')->insert(
    $rows
);
```

Comment: not miniual it  is coming form form how can we insert this

Comment: we must use loop

Comment: it was just an example, check your date value, may be it need qoutes

Comment: it is not key and value

Comment: Doesn't work, since it's missing the column names

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're passing the `price` as array `'price' => $request->price,`

it supposed be passed with key

```
foreach ($product_id as $key => $id) {
    $values[] = [
        'price'      => $request[$key]->price,
    ];
}
```